# EL expression in js function on jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp, el

Can I use el expressions in js functions that are on jsp page?
I have tried to do so, but the jsp compiler was always complaining that `==` symbol is not allowed here:

```
function somefunction() {
  var booleanExpression = '${myBean.a == -1}';
  ....
}
```

`myBean` is a request scope attribute that has an integer property `a`. I also have tried to use `eq` instead of `==`, but the error remains the same and that is weird.

I want my `boleanExpression` to be `true` or `false` in result.

Comment: If "a" is really an integer property, then the EL will not give a syntax error. You should post the exact error message (the exception) that you're getting. In general, JSP has *absolutely no idea* whether the output is going into JavaScript or HTML, or anything else for that matter. It has no way of knowing and it doesn't care.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave off the quotes.

```
var booleanExpression = ${myBean.a == -1};
```

JSP will dump out either `true` or `false`, with either of which JavaScript will be perfectly happy.

Comment: I have tried at first without quotes, but when got that error, put that expression into quotes

Comment: @maks please post the error you're getting; there's nothing wrong with that syntax.

Comment: I've unintentionally press format on that jsp in IDE and it formatted that line as 2, so second line starts from `==` symbol, but EL expressions seem not allowed to be multiline. The problem is solved.

Comment: @maks What IDE are you using?